# How do I realize communication between child and parent component via click?

Tags: angular, typescript, parent-child

I have two components. The parent component contains a button, if I click on the button child it will be disabled and the child component opens and contains the button close. When can I close the child component and enabled the button in the parent component?

My Code:

```
// Parent
<app-child (currentChild)="setCurrentChild($event)" *ngIf="showChild"></app-child>
 <button type="button" (click)="openChild()" [disabled]="isDisabled">Child</button>

public showChild = false;
public isDisabled = false;

openChild() {
this.showChild = true;
this.isDisabled = true;
}
```

```
// Child
<button class="btn-close" mat-button (click)="closeChild()">close</button>

 @Output() public currentChild: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

closeChild() {
this.showChild = false;
this.isDisabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the child component from within your child component? You can't do that, but you can emit an event to the parent which then sets `showChild` to false.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed some variables for better readability.

put this code also in your parent component:

```
closeChild() {
this.showChild = false;
this.isDisabled = false;
}
```

then modify your child element:

```
<app-child (onCloseChild)="closeChild()" *ngIf="showChild"></app-child>
```

In your child files you do the following:

```
<button class="btn-close" mat-button (click)="sendCloseEvent()">close</button>
```

```
@Output() public onCloseChild: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

sendCloseEvent() {
  this.onCloseChild.emit(true);
}
```

This will send an Event through the emitter and your parent is listening to it. As soon as it reaches the parent, it will call `closeChild()`.